# MIN and MAX redefines macros?

Tags: macos

I'm porting some Windows C code using SDL to the Mac. It currently uses DEFs for MIN and MAX. On OSX, this gives me a warning about a redefinition, as these appear to be in stdlib.

Do I care about this warning?

If so, what is the right way to attack this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix the warning by only defining MAX and MIN if they're not there already.

For example

```
#ifndef MAX
#define MAX(...) // your definition
#endif
```